# How to share my location on Facebook through Android App?

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

I wanna share/post my location on Facebook via my Kotlin app. It is possible? I already know is possible share content (link, image and text) with:

> startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share link using"))

But actually I wanna post my location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you try this:
This is java will automatically convert to kotlin when you paste code.

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +loc.getLatitude()+","+loc.getLongitude();
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my location");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share with:"));
```

Comment: Oh thanks! There's a way in which I could add text as default?

Comment: "my location" text. won't appear in Facebook app when its selected from chooser, as added location link